# How should I store/index and search against addresses in Cognitive Search?

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I am indexing documents, each can have multiple addresses which is currently analyzed with the Lucene analyzer (I'm open to switching to a different or custom analyzer). Currently I'm just storing the addresses as a string `123 Seasame St Seattle WA 12345 US`. I'm provided an address string that I'd like to use in a query to find documents with that address say `123 Sesame Street Seattle WA 12345-4567, US`.

My google-fu is failing me in that I can't find any documentation or examples of this.

When I'm making a query to search against it, I'm adding fuzzy search to try to match against what's stored on the document, but it won't work if the query has an extended zip code, or missing the country code, or uses street instead of st. So my search query could look something like this `123~ Seasame~ Street~ Seattle~ WA~ 12345-4567,~` with SearchMode being All not Any which won't match (any pulls completely unrelated results).

The documents are currently stored like this

```
{
    "docID":"32",
    "addresses":[
        "123 Sesame St Seattle WA 12345, US",
        "456 2nd Avr Washington DC 98765, USA"
    ]
}
```

Is there a better way for me to index (maybe as a complex object?) and/or a better way to search against the documents to get better results?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a better way to index and search addresses in Azure Cognitive Search by using complex types and a combination of analyzers. You can create a complex type for addresses and break down the address into separate fields, such as street, city, state, zip code, and country. This approach will give you more flexibility and control over your search queries.

Here's how you can modify your document schema:

```
{
    "docID": "32",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "street": "123 Sesame St",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "WA",
            "zip": "12345",
            "country": "US"
        },
        {
            "street": "456 2nd Avr",
            "city": "Washington",
            "state": "DC",
            "zip": "98765",
            "country": "USA"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can then create an index definition in Azure Cognitive Search with custom analyzers for each field. Here's an example using the standard.lucene analyzer for the street, city, and state fields, and the keyword analyzer for the zip and country fields:

```
{
    "name": "your-index-name",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "docID",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "key": true,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "name": "addresses",
            "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "street",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "analyzer": "standard.lucene"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "analyzer": "standard.lucene"
                },
                {
                    "name": "state",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "analyzer": "standard.lucene"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                {
                    "name": "country",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this new index structure, you can now search for addresses using individual fields. For instance, if you want to search for documents with the address "123 Sesame Street Seattle WA 12345-4567, US", you can break down the query into separate fields and perform the search like this:

```
search=addresses/street:123~ Sesame~ Street~ AND addresses/city:Seattle~ AND addresses/state:WA~ AND addresses/zip:12345 AND addresses/country:US
```

This approach allows you to handle variations in the address format more effectively and provides better search results. Additionally, by using different analyzers for each field, you can better control how each part of the address is tokenized and matched during the search.